# Why don't I have permission to my own VMs in vmware workstation?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

Starting today, as soon as I tried to open any of my VMs, I get this error:

```
VMware Workstation cannot connect to the virtual machine. Make sure you have rights to run the program, access all directories the program uses, and access all directories for temporary files.

Failed to connect pipe to virtual machine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Why is this so? Last time this happened, I had to refresh my machine. I simply cannot do this every time I run into this error.

Comment: Which OS is your host system?

Comment: It sounds like your virtual HDD is corrupt/missing.  Verify that is the case then restore it from a backup.

Comment: If you're running on Windows, is the "VMware Authorization Service" running?

Answer (score 0):

Try Killing all the VMware **Processes** and Starting up VMware again.

If that does not work **start a new VM** to possibly fix the issue with one of the steps below.

Try creating a **new VM**, and attach the disk from the corrupted VM to it as the primary disk.

If the disk itself isn't corrupted, it should boot right up.

Steps.
**1.Shut down the virtual machine.
2.On the Fusion menu bar, go to Virtual Machine > Settings.
3.Click Add Device > Existing Hard Disk, then click Add.
4.Navigate to the location of the virtual hard disk that you want to add and 5.select the main disk (.vmdk).
6.Select Share this virtual disk with the virtual machine that created it, then click Open.
7.Close the Settings pane and power on the virtual machine.**

If it doesn't boot, you can try attaching the virtual drive to a newly installed VM as a second disk, and trying to recover your files. Use the same steps above.

Please **note** im not on my personal computer at home but I have done this before with the issue you had with a windows 8.1 install on vmware.